# Restart in safe mode on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, settings, power-options

I have an unrooted Verizon Galaxy Nexus, just recently upgraded to Jelly Bean.

One of the touted features of Jelly Bean was the addition of the "Restart in safe mode" option from the power menu. (Long-press power button.)

However, no such option is available. In fact, it's the exact same options I saw under Android 4.0.4 (Power off; Airplane mode; silent; vibrate-only; sound on).

Is there a setting I missed? Or is this really a hardware option for the Nexus 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the Nexus 7 there's not a separate menu option for "Reboot into safe mode". You have to long press on "Power off" and then the safe mode dialog appears. I'd try that, since I imagine it would work the same way if the GNex supports it.

Comment: Oh, darn. Yeah, it sure does. (Feeling a bit sheepish.)

Comment: That screen should have a warning that it makes synced accounts and widgets disappear, tried it just to see what it's like and poof, they're gone!

Comment: @onik- Even after you reboot into normal mode?